# Require entire folder with ruby files in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I need to require a folder with a lot of files:

```
require './models/request_builders/ipg_request_builder.rb'
require './models/request_builders/omnipay_request_builder.rb'
require './models/request_builders/girogate_request_builder.rb'
```

How I can require the entire folder?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer :**

```
Dir['/path/*.rb'].each { |file| require file }
```

**Explanation :**

`Dir[]` is an equivalent of calling `Dir.glob()` which take a pattern string and returns an array containing the matching filenames. (cf. more detail about patterns https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Dir.html#glob-method)

Exemple with a given directory `myDirectory` at filesystem root containing only `file1.rb` and `file2.rb`, `Dir['/myDirectory/*.rb']` will return :

```
[
  '/myDirectory/file1.rb',
  '/myDirectory/file2.rb'
]
```

Knowing how `Dir.glob` works, we just need to iterate on the list of files by passing their names in the `require` method :

```
Dir['/myDirectory/*.rb'].each { |file_name| require file_name }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.